# Android things - Raspberry pi 3 model B, raspi-config command not found

Tags: pi-3, i2c, android-things

I have searched for the solution before posting this question.

I've flashed Android things OS on my SD card mounted to Raspberry Pi 3.

Now I want to configure MPU6050 to access Gyroscope and accelerometer!

I installed i2c tools using below command

```
sudo apt-get install -y i2c-tools
```

Below command...

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 2 (or 1)
```

shows

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

So, I want to configure raspberry pi 3. I tried with this command

```
sudo raspi-config
```

**Error - sudo: raspi-config: command not found.**

I tried installing using this command

```
sudo apt-get install raspi-config
```

*Result is...*

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package raspi-config
```

How to solve this??

Comment: Perhaps andoid-things repo doesn't have raspi-config as that's a "raspbian" thing

Comment: If you are going to cross-post you could at least edit the rubbish.

Comment: @JaromandaX So, is there a way to add it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

raspi-config is just an script that makes easier to configure some values or preferences from your Linux distro (focused heavily on Debian, take that on mind)

You can find the actual github project at https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config

You can clone it by using git:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config.git
```

Comment: I cloned it! but still couldn't find the file

Comment: Once cloned, go to the folder. Inside should appear all the files from the project. One of them is raspi-config. Grant permissions of execution to that file (chmod +x raspi-config). After that , execute it as sudo

Comment: The folder is in home. I granted permission as well. sudo raspi-config command still says - COMMAND NOT FOUND

Comment: It isan script. Call it with sudo ./raspi-config or sudo sh raspi-config